# Adding events to events array returned from server FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) to render events in my web application. I am getting the json feed of events from server using following method

```
events: {
            url: '/api/availability/events',
            error: function () {
                //alert("some error fetching events");
            }
        }
```

The events are returned and rendered fine by the full calendar and here is the view of those events in the calendar.
[image: Current View of Full Calendar]
The requirement is to show a default event on each day for which server has not returned any event. Like, I want to display event on each empty cell with title `Available for All meals`.

And the requirement is that this should be done on client side and server should not know anything about the default event. So my question is how I can change the events array after it is returned from the server and add a default event for each empty day (where empty day = a day with no events).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following method from [fullcalendar documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/)

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'myxmlfeed.php',
            dataType: 'xml',
            data: {
                // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                start: start.unix(),
                end: end.unix()
            },
            success: function(doc) {
                var events = [];
                $(doc).find('event').each(function() {
                    events.push({
                        title: $(this).attr('title'),
                        start: $(this).attr('start') // will be parsed
                    });
                });
                //append custom events here
                callback(events);
            }
        });
    }
});
```